# Structure pointer loses data

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

So I'm trying to build a linked list which can accept any data type, more like a non-homogenous list.

```
#define CNode malloc (sizeof(listnode));
#define CNodeContent malloc (sizeof(content));

typedef enum datatypes {
    CHAR,
    INT ,
    FLOAT,
    STRING,
    LIST
}datatype;

typedef struct contentInfo {
    void *data;
    datatype type;
}content;

typedef struct node {
    content* val;
    struct node *next;
} listnode;

typedef listnode* list;


// Creating content
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

content* createContentInt(int val) {
    content *newContent = CNodeContent;
    newContent->type= INT;
    newContent->data = &val;
    return newContent;
}

content* createContentFloat(float val) {
    content *newContent = CNodeContent;
    newContent->type= FLOAT;
    (newContent->data) = &val;
    return newContent;
}

content* createContentChar(char val) {
    content *newContent = CNodeContent;
    newContent->type= CHAR;
    newContent->data = &val;
    return newContent;
}

content* createContentString(char* val) {
    content *newContent = CNodeContent;
    newContent->type= STRING;
    newContent->data = val;
    return newContent;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// List Functions

list createList(content *cont) {
    list newnode = CNode;
    printf("\n--%d--value: %d ",(cont->type),*((int*)cont->data));
    newnode->val = cont;
    printf("<leh %d >",(newnode->val->type));
    newnode->next= NULL;
    return newnode;
}
int main() {
  list llist = createList(createContentInt(4));
  content * c = createContentInt(5);
  printf("Main-> %d <",(*(int*)c->data));
  createList(c);
  /* append(llist,c); */
  /* display(llist); */
  /* append(llist,createContentInt(5)); */
  /* append(llist,createContentInt(6)); */
  /* display(llist); */
  return 0;
}
```

So here is the problem:

When I call `createContentInt(4)`, it returns the content node properly,
but as soon I as call `createList` or the `append` function with the same content node, the value `data` is set to `0`.

I checked the return value from `createContentInt` and what not everything works fine except when in `createList` or `append`.

Moreover, the `content->type` also has the appropriate value but `data` has lost its.

I have agonized a lot over this searching over the forum and what not but can't seem to find the reason why the value is being set to `0`
.
Another thing I figured out is if I use something like this:

```
newContent->data = (int*)4;
```

the code works fine. What is the difference?

Please, someone, give some insights over why it is not working.
Any alternate solutions would be highly appreciated, though I'm more inclined to know why it isn't working.

Comment: Getting references to stack based variables is a Bad Idea™.

Comment: @Lousy Could you please argument?

Comment: `newContent->data = &val;` stores address of `val`. Think about what will happen to `val` when you return from `createContent***` function: It's destroyed, and your address is invalid.

Comment: Well, for example, `int val` is passed as a parameter and placed somewhere on the stack, meaning that once you exit the `createContentInt` function, the `data` pointer points to the stack area which has been popped. OP needs to use `malloc` to create the space somewhere on the heap. Alternatively, for a smaller set of possible "content" types, `data` could be a `union` of all the possible values user can pass, because then it would be copied by value. That's a dirtier solution maintenance-wise, but reduces the number of allocations.

Comment: @user694733 Thank you so very much. That makes perfect sense..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
newContent->data = &val;
```

You are assigning `data` with the ADDRESS of your function's parameter (which is on the stack).

If the register that holds `val` is re-used through successive calls the content of `data` is overwritten.

More generally, once you exit the function the address of `val` can be reused at leisure so `data` will point to garbage.

instead you could, for example:

```
newContent->data = malloc(sizeof(TYPE)); // Set TYPE to INT/CHAR/...
// test return of malloc
memcpy(newContent->data, &val, sizeof(TYPE));
// Note that you will need an extra function to free() the allocated memory
```